# Compare two files for text match

Tags: python

I have a text representation of a file tree (treesample.csv), and another file with a listing of files(filesToTest.txt).
I'm trying to read treesample.csv, and search it for each line in filesToTest.txt, and print the matching line. From what I can tell, my nested for loops below should do the trick, but I can't get it to match.

```
with open("c:/temp/treesample.csv") as file:
    treelines = file.readlines()

with open("c:/temp/filesToTest.txt") as file2:
    testlines = file2.readlines()


for line in treelines:
    for line2 in testlines:
        if line2 in line:
           print("found !", line)
```

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of the two input files. Your comments show the format of both files to be different. The file paths must be the same to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import filecmp
  
f1 = "file1.txt"
f2 = "file2.txt"
  
# shallow comparison
result = filecmp.cmp(f1, f2)
print(result)
# deep comparison
result = filecmp.cmp(f1, f2, shallow=False)
print(result)
```

or with see the diff

```
# reading files
f1 = open("1.txt", "r")  
f2 = open("2.txt", "r")  
  
i = 0
  
for line1 in f1:
    i += 1
      
    for line2 in f2:
          
        # matching line1 from both files
        if line1 == line2:  
            # print IDENTICAL if similar
            print("Line ", i, ": IDENTICAL")       
        else:
            print("Line ", i, ":")
            # else print that line from both files
            print("\tFile 1:", line1, end='')
            print("\tFile 2:", line2, end='')
        break
  
# closing files
f1.close()                                       
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
import difflib
  
with open('file1.txt') as file_1:
    file_1_text = file_1.readlines()
  
with open('file2.txt') as file_2:
    file_2_text = file_2.readlines()
  
# Find and print the diff:
for line in difflib.unified_diff(
        file_1_text, file_2_text, fromfile='file1.txt', 
        tofile='file2.txt', lineterm=''):
    print(line)
```

or if you want another way to do that. refer to the link below
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compare-two-files-line-by-line-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

If just want to find the matching lines in two files then can iterate over one of list of lines and check if it is found in the second list. Don't need nested for loops.

```python
f1 = "1.txt"
f2 = "2.txt"

with open(f1, "r") as file:
    treelines = file.readlines()

with open(f2, "r") as file2:
    testlines = file2.readlines()

for line in treelines:
    if line in testlines:
        print("found !", line.rstrip())
```

Can do the same thing with list comprehension.

```python
matches = [line for line in treelines if line in testlines]
for line in matches:
    print("found !", line.rstrip())
```

Comment: thanks @codemonkey, that certainly looks like the simplest way, but unfortunately, no matches are found. 

If I do something like teststring = "testword", then code something like: if teststring in treelines: It works.

Comment: @kilgore Do both files have the same line endings \n vs \r\n, etc ? Would help with a notional example of what file1 and file2 might look like.

Comment: And I did try using a single word as a line in the test file, but still, no matches.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey,
Both files are UTF8 with CRLF line endings
My treesample.csv looks like this:
```
"12/14/2021 1:17:21 AM","H:\Roots\Shared\Final Docs\File Name"
"12/14/2021 4:28:57 AM","H:\Roots\Shared\Final Docs\Security"
"12/14/2021 4:28:57 AM","H:\Roots\Shared\Certs"
"12/14/2021 4:31:52 AM","H:\Roots\Shared\other stuff"
"12/14/2021 1:17:55 AM","H:\Roots\Shared\Things here
```

Comment: @kilgore Please update your question with the sample input files. Comments makes a mess of the formatting.

Comment: OK, finally figuring out how to format comments:

filesToTest looks like:  
Final Docs\ Sessions    
"Final Docs\File Name"    
Final Docs\File Name    
Security    
"Security"    
debug-test failure

Comment: @kilgore - That's the problem there. If filesToTest.txt format doesn't match treesample.csv then won't get a match. Must extract just the filename from the CSV file and add that to a list.

Comment: I'll take that route.  Thank you.
I thought it would be something simple.

Thank you.